# How to turn on blog function?

Tags: how-to

there! We are using a very dated version of EE (2003- 2010). I am not proficient in web management, so I need a lot of help getting this website updated. First thing's first... How do I start blogging? 
Thanks!
NFM

Comment: Do you have any more details? Could you provide an ExpressionEngine version # for us? And the answer as to how to start blogging is extremely dependent on how your EE install is configure (what channels, templates, etc...).

Comment: Hey, NashvilleFarmersMarket. See Jeremy's answer for a good way to get started. Then update your original question here or post a new one that's more specific. See the [help center](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help) for more on asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there's not a "blog function". Content in ExpressionEngine is stored in channels, or weblogs in older versions of EE. A channel contains a collection of entries, which could be blog posts, pages, or any other type of content. Entries are made up of a set of fields, which represent the different information you put into an entry, such as title, body, description, image, etc.

I'd suggest reading the documentation or some tutorials to get a better handle on how EE works, and then come back here with more specific questions later, which I'm sure someone will be happy to help you with.